# Netbeans with Nette\Tester code coverage results in: No tests executed

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, code-coverage, nette-tester

I have a simple PHP project set up in Netbeans with Nette\Tester for unit tests. When I execute tests without code coverage everything works as intended. However when I turn code coverage feature on I get message "No tests executed for project ..."

Update: Mentioned "project" is NOT a Nette project. It is actually few classes without dependencies located in /src.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I didn't have xdebug enabled.